Introducing Stackpoints. Rewarding system for StackExchange community
Stackpoints fully community based platform rewarding StackExchange community for their valuable contribution to platform based on their reputation.
Platform allow to bounty Question and answer to encourage members to write quality contents. based on votes bounty will be distributed to respective content creator.

Test Demo: https://youtu.be/DJNb2ZgrYLs
twitter: https://x.com/StackPointsApp

